# I wan to limit user to increase/descrease font size

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add font size increment+decrement functionality to my website and yeah, I did it.
Now the fact is when user click on increase button, the font size increasing continuously and the same thing happens to decrease button.
But I don't want this. I want when someone click on increase button, the font size will increase only once... and same for the decrease button.

JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zux360q5/) here

And heere is the code I'm working with.

**This is the markup**

```
<div id="settings">
  <button class="resetFont clean-gray">Reset Font Size</button>
  <button class="increaseFont clean-gray">Increase Font Size</button>
  <button class="decreaseFont clean-gray">Decrease Font Size</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <h2>
  This is a test heading
  </h2>
   <p>
    This is a test paragraph
   </p>
</div>
```

**And this is the script**
    var defaultFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

```
$(".resetFont").click(function () {
    $('html').css('font-size', defaultFontSize);
});

$(".increaseFont").click(function () {
    var fontSize = getFontSize();
    var newFontSize = fontSize + 1;
    setFontSize(newFontSize);
    return false;
});

$(".decreaseFont").click(function () {
    var fontSize = getFontSize();
    var newFontSize = fontSize - 1;
    setFontSize(newFontSize);
    return false;
});

function getFontSize() {
    var currentSize = $("html").css("font-size");
    var currentSizeNumber = parseFloat(currentSize, 12);
    if (currentSizeNumber > 24) {
        currentSizeNumber = 24;
    }
    if (currentSizeNumber < 10) {
        currentSizeNumber = 10;
    }
    return currentSizeNumber;
}

function setFontSize(size) {
    $("html").css("font-size", size);
    $(".actualSize").html(size);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the increase/decrease button code like below

```
$(".increaseFont").click(function () {
    var newFontSize =  parseFloat(defaultFontSize) + 1;
    setFontSize(newFontSize);
    return false;
});

$(".decreaseFont").click(function () {
  var newFontSize =  parseFloat(defaultFontSize) - 1;
    setFontSize(newFontSize);
    return false;
});
```

js fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/c2owfaqk/2/)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. It's really helpful

Comment: Prabhat Kumar, Hi again... Could you please help me with this? if I want to increase/decrease font size all of the elements that are on my webpage but without header??

Comment: @Omar you can one thing wrap your elements in a container which you want to zoom and give a #id to your container. After that you can apply `$('#id').css("font-size", size)`

Comment: Thanks a lot... Definitely I'll give a try

Comment: Ok!! and what happens to this solution , Initially you accepted the solution but now it is in not accepted state.

Comment: can you write your complete code on JSfiddle ? and send me the link.

Comment: @prabhat_kumar, Hi again... if I want to increase the font-size three times then what to do?? could you please tell me?? I'm trying to do it by myself with your provided script! but still not getting any improvment

Comment: Please help me with this issue!!

Comment: Ok wait I am creating a fiddle for you.

Comment: Hi Omar !! Check this code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-microservice-43pwh) https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-microservice-43pwh

Comment: It's really great... you are so helpfull

Comment: If you don't mind... it's the last.... if I want all the element's font size will increase/decrease then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Cache the minimum and maximum size you want to the text to go:

```
const minSize = parseFloat(defaultFontSize, 12) - 1;
const maxSize = parseFloat(defaultFontSize, 12) + 1;
```

And then check to see if the new decreased/increased size stays within those bounds:

```
// in the increasefont click handler
if (newFontSize <= maxSize) setFontSize(newFontSize);

// in the decreasefont click handler
if (newFontSize >= minSize) setFontSize(newFontSize);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qhw8g06r/)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the buttons when max or min font size is reached. Just ensure to reset them when the font size is reset.

```js
const defaultFontSize = 12;
let actualFontSize = defaultFontSize;
setFontSize(defaultFontSize);

$(".resetFont").click(function() {
  setFontSize(defaultFontSize);
  $(".decreaseFont").removeAttr('disabled');
  $(".increaseFont").removeAttr('disabled');
});

$(".increaseFont").click(function() {
  actualFontSize += 1;
  setFontSize(actualFontSize);
  if (actualFontSize > defaultFontSize) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $(".decreaseFont").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  return false;
});

$(".decreaseFont").click(function() {
  actualFontSize -= 1;
  setFontSize(actualFontSize);
  if (actualFontSize < defaultFontSize) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $(".increaseFont").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  return false;
});

function setFontSize(size) {
  $("html").css("font-size", size + "px");
  $(".actualSize").html(size);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#settings {
  padding-right: 1.250em;
  padding-top: 0.750em;
}

button.clean-gray {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #eee;
}

button.clean-gray:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border: #bbb solid 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ddd;
}

button.clean-gray:active {
  border: #aaa solid 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #aaaaaa inset, 0 1px 0 0 #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="settings">
  <button class="resetFont clean-gray">Reset Font Size</button>
  <button class="increaseFont clean-gray">Increase Font Size</button>
  <button class="decreaseFont clean-gray">Decrease Font Size</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <h2>
    This is a test heading
  </h2>
  <p>
    This is a test paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's also nice... But what if I want to increase/decrease font size all of the elements except header??